# Why is the ViewModel data null on POST ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing forms on ASP .NET MVC 5. I thought it was simple enough to just post with a matching model in the action but I keep getting null values on my action. For example,

```
@model Tuple<ManageLoginsViewModel, IndexViewModel, LocalPasswordModel, SetPasswordViewModel>

<p>
    You do not have a local password for this site. Add a local
    password so you can log in without an external login.
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetPassword", "Manage", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Set Password</legend>
        <div>
            <div class="LabelPassword">
                <label>New password</label>
                <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The New password must be at least 6 characters long." 
                    data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length-min="6" 
                    data-val-required="The New password field is required." 
                    id="NewPassword" type="password">
            </div>
            <div class="LabelPassword">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input data-val="true" data-val-length="The New password must be at least 6 characters long." 
                    data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length-min="6" 
                    data-val-required="The New password field is required." 
                    id="ConfirmPassword" type="password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Set password" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

While numerous post suggest on renaming the action parameter to something that doesn't match the properties on my view model, I have not found a solution to this.

[image]

weirdly enough, there is no post data that Chrome shows. Is this an error in my html or my handling of the post?

and finally, here's the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SetPassword(SetPasswordViewModel setPassword)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId(), setPassword.NewPassword);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = ManageMessageId.SetPasswordSuccess });
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(setPassword);
        }
```

I'm sure its something simple, but I've got no indication where things are going wrong now, other then the blanks on POST that is shown in Chrome (well, the anti-forgery token is displayed at least). Is this the problem?

Comment: Set the `name` attributes on the input form - same as you have in `SetPasswordViewModel`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be simple.

Comment: You may as well remove all those `data-*` attributes your manually adding - they are useless in your case. Then you should go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials and learn how to use MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the name attribute on your inputs to be the same as the properties in your parameter (SetPasswordViewModel).  Mvc uses the name to map the parameters

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your model name object not match with any its property. Example Passing the model object in controller action.

```
public class QuestionModel
{ 
  [Required]
  public string Question { get; set; }
)

public ActionResult Index(QuestionModel Question)
{

}
```

look into above example where Question property matching with its model object name in action controller.